# passing SOAP req: Passing ItemNo String but it cannot locate the Codeunit which is exposed as a web service in NAV 2018

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, nav

Im calling an exposed codeunit (func GetItemPic) in NAV 2018 but i am getting the response that it can not be found but it is exposed.
Can anybody help me, why is this happening, i also checked verified if the service exists or not in the 'services' list by making up the url. http://DESKTOP-xxxx:1234/DynamicsNAV110/WS/CRONUS%20Danmark%20A%2FS/services

[This is my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZQr.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn59X.png)

[and this is the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRzDz.png)

The CU XML is provided below:

```
    <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations">
<element name="PostItemJournal">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostItemJournal_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostItemRecJournal">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostItemRecJournal_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostPurchOrderMS">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="documentNo" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostPurchOrderMS_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostSalesOrderMS">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="documentNo" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="PostSalesOrderMS_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence/>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetItemPic">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="itemNo" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetItemPic_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="SetItemPic">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="itemNo" type="string"/>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="fileName" type="string"/>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="base64Image" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="SetItemPic_Result">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
</schema>
</types>
<message name="PostItemJournal">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostItemJournal"/>
</message>
<message name="PostItemJournal_Result">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostItemJournal_Result"/>
</message>
<message name="PostItemRecJournal">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostItemRecJournal"/>
</message>
<message name="PostItemRecJournal_Result">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostItemRecJournal_Result"/>
</message>
<message name="PostPurchOrderMS">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostPurchOrderMS"/>
</message>
<message name="PostPurchOrderMS_Result">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostPurchOrderMS_Result"/>
</message>
<message name="PostSalesOrderMS">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostSalesOrderMS"/>
</message>
<message name="PostSalesOrderMS_Result">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PostSalesOrderMS_Result"/>
</message>
<message name="GetItemPic">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:GetItemPic"/>
</message>
<message name="GetItemPic_Result">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:GetItemPic_Result"/>
</message>
<message name="SetItemPic">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:SetItemPic"/>
</message>
<message name="SetItemPic_Result">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:SetItemPic_Result"/>
</message>
<portType name="MSOperations_Port">
<operation name="PostItemJournal">
<input name="PostItemJournal" message="tns:PostItemJournal"/>
<output name="PostItemJournal_Result" message="tns:PostItemJournal_Result"/>
</operation>
<operation name="PostItemRecJournal">
<input name="PostItemRecJournal" message="tns:PostItemRecJournal"/>
<output name="PostItemRecJournal_Result" message="tns:PostItemRecJournal_Result"/>
</operation>
<operation name="PostPurchOrderMS">
<input name="PostPurchOrderMS" message="tns:PostPurchOrderMS"/>
<output name="PostPurchOrderMS_Result" message="tns:PostPurchOrderMS_Result"/>
</operation>
<operation name="PostSalesOrderMS">
<input name="PostSalesOrderMS" message="tns:PostSalesOrderMS"/>
<output name="PostSalesOrderMS_Result" message="tns:PostSalesOrderMS_Result"/>
</operation>
<operation name="GetItemPic">
<input name="GetItemPic" message="tns:GetItemPic"/>
<output name="GetItemPic_Result" message="tns:GetItemPic_Result"/>
</operation>
<operation name="SetItemPic">
<input name="SetItemPic" message="tns:SetItemPic"/>
<output name="SetItemPic_Result" message="tns:SetItemPic_Result"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="MSOperations_Binding" type="tns:MSOperations_Port">
<binding xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="PostItemJournal">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations:PostItemJournal" style="document"/>
<input name="PostItemJournal">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="PostItemJournal_Result">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="PostItemRecJournal">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations:PostItemRecJournal" style="document"/>
<input name="PostItemRecJournal">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="PostItemRecJournal_Result">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="PostPurchOrderMS">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations:PostPurchOrderMS" style="document"/>
<input name="PostPurchOrderMS">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="PostPurchOrderMS_Result">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="PostSalesOrderMS">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations:PostSalesOrderMS" style="document"/>
<input name="PostSalesOrderMS">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="PostSalesOrderMS_Result">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="GetItemPic">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations:GetItemPic" style="document"/>
<input name="GetItemPic">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="GetItemPic_Result">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="SetItemPic">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MSOperations:SetItemPic" style="document"/>
<input name="SetItemPic">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output name="SetItemPic_Result">
<body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="MSOperations">
<port name="MSOperations_Port" binding="tns:MSOperations_Binding">
<address xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" location="http://desktop-pll1kkl:11047/DynamicsNAV110/WS/CRONUS%20Danmark%20A%252FS/Codeunit/MSOperations"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just took too long to notice, if you can see in the response img, the company translated from the url was coming out as CRONUS Danmark A%2FS/...... it should have been translated as CRONUS Danmark A/S. I just renamed the company (removed the / which was creating problems translating i think) as CRONUS Danmark AS and the request went through.